# How to solve file permissions error with subprocess in Cloud Functions?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, subprocess

I am trying to run a binary using subprocess in a Google Cloud Function, based on this example from https://github.com/zdenulo/google-cloud-functions-system-packages/tree/master/cf_ascii:

```
import os
import subprocess
import logging

from flask import make_response

def main(request):
    text = request.args.get('text', '')
    if not text:
        return 'missing text parameter', 404
    logging.info(f'received url: {text}')

    cmd = f"./figlet -d fonts {text}".split(' ')
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
    error = stderr.decode('utf8')
    if error:
        return error, 403
    out = stdout.decode('utf8')
    response = make_response(out)
    response.headers["content-type"] = "text/plain"
    return response
```

From what I have read this should be possible, but I get this error when executing it:

```
...
File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1522, in _execute_child
raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './figlet'
```

So the function seems to lack the correct permissions, but I cannot figure out why (file permission settings, IAM/Service Account permissions...). What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error suggests to me that ./figlet does not have its executable bit set.  You should make sure that's the case before deploying:

```
chmod a+x figlet
```

If you're deploying from windows, you might not have an option, other than to get a linux or macos machine to deploy from.

Comment: Thanks! I had to deploy from Linux to solve this, like you said.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a path to the file relative to where your source file exists, not relative to where the file is being executed from. When your function is invoked on Cloud Functions, they are not the same.

Try the following:

```py
import os
this_dir, this_filename = os.path.split(__file__)
path_to_figlet = os.path.join(this_dir, 'figlet')
cmd = [path_to_figlet, '-d', 'fonts', text]
```